# ImportError: No module named qgis.core

Tags: python, ubuntu, module, importerror, qgis

I am on Ubuntu 13.04. I get the following error message -

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "analyse.py", line 1, in <module>
        from log import shelve
      File "/home/shubham/SMART/TaxiData/log.py", line 27, in <module>
        from demo import *
      File "/home/shubham/SMART/zones/demo.py", line 5, in <module>
        from qgis.core import *
    ImportError: No module named qgis.core
```

Actually, everything was working fine till today morning. I guess this might be due to a package update.

I tried looking around on Google but my search was fruitless. So, I will really appreciate any help or pointers you guys can give :)

Thanks.

Comment: which package did you update?

Comment: I have copied and pasted the dpkg.log file here - http://pastebin.com/b1ZihLbt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by completely removing the installation and using the nightly builds at    'deb http://qgis.org/debian-nightly raring main'.

Answer (score -1):

If you have `pip` installed you could either try `pip search qgis` or `pip freeze`. The latter shows a list of all installed python packages to check if you have the package. Maybe try reinstalling qgis ...

Comment: 'pip search qgis' only gives 'qgsctx' which is not what I want. I installed qgis using 'sudo apt-get install qgis'. I have tried removing and reinstalling it too but that didn't help.

Comment: Yes, and it gave the expected 'No distributions at all found for qgis
'

Answer (score -1):

Try `sudo apt-get install python-qgis` . The package does not appear to be available on PyPI, but it was listed as "python-qgis" in the Ubuntu packages.